# Fragment onResume doesn't get called after Fragment is being detached and then re-attached

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm trying to get the handle on all the new ActionBar and Fragments API.
I have an main activity, and I want it to manage two different tabs.
I'm using the ActionBarSherlock in order to support older version than ICS.

Each tab contains its own `Fragment` (each one is a subclass of `SherlockListFragment`)
I got it to work basically nice, but I have a problem that I'm sure that is stupid, but I can't figure it out yet:

On the first time each Fragment is shown, everything is OK, the list is populated and so the MenuItems in the ActionBar.

But the second time you see a tab (After swicth and switch-back), Neither the list get populated, nor the ActionBar MenuItems.

This is how I'm switching the tabs:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    SherlockListFragment toAttach = // Find the right fragment here...

    if (toAttach != null) {
        if (toAttach.isAdded() == false) {
            transaction.add(R.id.tab_placeholder, toAttach,
                    REMINDER_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        } else {
            transaction.attach(toAttach);
        }
    }
}
```

And onTabUneselect  I'm detaching the Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    SherlockListFragment toDetach = // Find the right fragment
    if (toDetach != null) {
        transaction.detach(toDetach);
    }
}
```

I'm populating the lists and the ActionBar menu in onResume:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    fillRemindersList();
}
```

I also tried it in onStart and onCreateView but it didn't help...

So what am I missing here?
And if there are others issues in my code that I'm unaware of, please do tell.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I just confirmed that `onResume` dosen't get called after I switch tabs, which is definetly wrong since I'm detaching and re-attaching them...
Am I switching tabs the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using transaction.remove(fragment) in onTabUnselected and transaction.replace in onTabSelected.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that this is the answer, though it is not relevant anymore, because I switched to List Navigation. (Make more sense in my case, and works perfectly :))

Comment: In my case calling 'FragmentTranaction.remove(fragment#1)' in fragment#1 just before calling 'FragmentTransaction.commit()' helps me to force fragment#1 go through onPause() ... onDestroyView() on replacing and go through onCreateView() ... onResume() when I return to fragment#1 pressing back button.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the beginTransaction() and commit() outside of this code I assume or did you forget?
You can see a trick used here from the samples as well:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java

Comment: Neither! As you can see I'm implementing the ActionBar.TabListener interface. In the TabListener callbacks you get a FragmentTransaction ready to use (That is - "beginned") and you **mus not** call commit as the documentation says explicitly.
Besides, the fragments are being swapped so it's not that...